# WCF Service CallBacks

Tags: wcf

On WCF callbacks, one doubt is still nagging in my mind, The callback happens only when the client makes a call to the server. Don't we have a mechanism that the client registers with the service, and after a while something happens at the server and the service notifies all the connected clients. In COM we do this by generating a COM exe server and keeping a list of all connected clients and trigger an event whenever the COM exe server deems necessary and that will end up as a callback at the client end.

Comment: Maybe you could add a code sample?

Comment: You can see this : Link:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17704/WCF-Duplex-Operations-and-UI-Threads

Comment: Just look at the "JoinTheParty" call, client class "JoinTheParty" and "JoinTheParty" makes a callback. This is what I intend to avoid

Comment: No actually in that example its not when THE client makes a call. Because you can have several clients and all the clients will get the callback

Comment: You are right the server calls all the client, but that happens only after the client makes a call to the server. This, I want to avoid. Client registers with the server and get timely callbacks, without any one particular client initiating the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at Duplex WCF bindings...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx

Another framework you may want to evaluate is NServiceBus ...

http://docs.particular.net/NServiceBus/how-pub-sub-works

Comment: I went through that, it is not helpfull as the client has still to call a service function to receive a callback, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: You need to read again the client declares a method, the server pushes a message to the client which results in that method being invoked on the client with the message pushed from the server

Comment: OK in the example the Callback.Equals is invoked on the service from within a method invoked by the client.  It's just an example.  The communication is still initiated from the server.  The point is something has to invoke the Callback methods, it could be a background thread running on a timer

Comment: Added another example.  Note in both examples the CallbackContract

Comment: Regarding the background Thread. We still have one issue the service is configured for [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]. This means one object persession, this means Ineed to have a static list of all clients

Comment: and then the background thread “somehow”  calls a method in the service and this method informs all connected clients. This is alright to start with, I thought we might just have this infrastructure in place, so we need not have to do this

Comment: If you want something more elaborate, I'd look at NServiceBus before rolling out your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking for a messaging implementation like MSMQ?

Using MSMQ, you can setup your client to be a subscriber to your server's "messages". The server in turn is your publisher and it will produce the effect you seem to desire.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Seems like there is no in built infra to do this, and we have to build this infra. I am ok with building it , only needed to know there is no eff the shelf solution available.

Comment: I am looking at if there exists an off the self wcf way of auto informing the clients.